# getting ROC curve from createLBPHFaceRecognizer

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I'm using [LBPHFaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#local-binary-patterns-histograms) on a face database.

I need to create a ROC curve of my results for a collage assignment.

from the predict function i get back the predicted label and the confidence.

So is there a way to create a ROC curve from this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the true value, and the predicted value, you can use sklearn builtin metric function:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.
My prob;em is that i dont really understand what i need to and to the function and how do i calculate all the needed array from the confidence i get from lbph predictions.